# QueryFailedError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "orders" TYPEORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to return only consumers who has in orderIds array with their order.but i Got this error any Idea?

```
const Tasks = await this.deliveryTaskRepo.find({
                    relations : ['order', 'order.status'],
                    where
                });
 let OrdersArray = Tasks.map((item) => {
                    return item.order.id
                })
                
 const result = await this.consumerRepo.createQueryBuilder('consumers')
                 .leftJoinAndSelect('consumers.orders', 'orders')
                 .where('consumers.orders.id IN(:ids)',{ids:OrdersArray})
                 .getMany();
 return result;
```

I have also tried

```
const result = await this.consumerRepo.find({
            relations:['orders'],
            where:(qb) => {
                qb.where(
                    'orders.id IN(ids)',{ids:OrdersArray}
                );
              }
        })
```

i Got error `QueryFailedError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "orders"` what i did wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.where('orders.id IN (:...ids)', { ids:OrdersArray })
```